# Generalize "$-notation"

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm still getting used to working in R and thought constructing a "simple" MACD-screener would be a great way to get into some of the inner workings of R. However, I  have encountered the following problem.
I've perfectly been able to calculate te MACD and signal line for a seperate stock. So now, in order to be able to scan multiple stocks, I have to generalize the code. My question in: "How can I use a variable (f.e. name of the stock currently being looked at) in the "$-notation"?
After this I'm planning to do a "for loop" iterating over the names of stocks in a list-object. Is this a practical way of doing it?

Below I've inserted the code I have till now. In this code I'm looking to replace the "QQQ" with a variable.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c('QQQ','SPY','APPL','MMM')

ema.s = 12
ema.l = 26
ema.k = 9
ema.t = 200

getSymbols(tickers, from = '2021-01-6',
           to = "2021-10-21",warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)

QQQ$QQQ.EMA.S <- EMA(QQQ[,6], n = ema.s)
QQQ$QQQ.EMA.L <- EMA(QQQ[,6], n = ema.l)
QQQ$QQQ.MACD <- QQQ$QQQ.EMA.S - QQQ$QQQ.EMA.L
QQQ$QQQ.SIG <- EMA(QQQ$QQQ.MACD, n = ema.k)
```

Comment: Don't use the `$` notation.  `x$y` is almost the same as `x[["y"]]`, so use the latter notation.  (The difference is that `x$y` will extract `x$y1` if `x$y` is not found, while the bracket notation will give `NULL`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tidyquant to all of this in one go.

```
library(tidyquant)

ema.s = 12
ema.l = 26

tickers <- c('QQQ','SPY','AAPL','MMM')

# get all the data in a tibble
stock_data <- tq_get(tickers, 
                     from = '2021-01-6',
                     to = "2021-10-21")


stock_data <- stock_data %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted,
            mutate_fun = MACD,
            n_fast = ema.s,
            n_slow = ema.l)

stock_data 

# A tibble: 800 x 10
# Groups:   symbol [4]
   symbol date        open  high   low close   volume adjusted  macd signal
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 QQQ    2021-01-06  307   312.  306.  308. 52809600     306.    NA     NA
 2 QQQ    2021-01-07  310.  316.  310.  315. 30394800     314.    NA     NA
 3 QQQ    2021-01-08  317.  319.  315.  319. 33955800     318.    NA     NA
 4 QQQ    2021-01-11  316.  317.  314.  314. 32746400     313.    NA     NA
 5 QQQ    2021-01-12  314.  316.  311.  314. 29266800     313.    NA     NA
 6 QQQ    2021-01-13  314.  317.  314.  316. 22898400     315.    NA     NA
 7 QQQ    2021-01-14  316.  318.  314.  314. 23500100     313.    NA     NA
 8 QQQ    2021-01-15  314.  315.  311.  312. 35118700     311.    NA     NA
 9 QQQ    2021-01-19  314.  317.  313.  316. 24537000     315.    NA     NA
10 QQQ    2021-01-20  320.  325.  317.  324. 30728100     323.    NA     NA
```

If you want to do this in base R functions combined with only quantmod functions, check the quantmod tag, there are a few posts that use `lapply` to do this. If you don't find what you need, let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot, does this method also work well for 100+ tickers? It has been running for some minutes now, yet not given any feedback?

Comment: It works, but it might take a bit of time. With a 100+ tickers there is a lot of transforming between xts and tibble formats and that will take time. To speed things up a different way might involve future package for parallel processing, data.table with lapply or other steps to refactor the code.

Comment: yes, it worked out well however this warning keeps popping up: Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` column `nested.col`.
ℹ `nested.col = purrr::map(...)`.
ℹ `type_convert()` only converts columns of type 'character'.
- `df` has no columns of type 'character'

Comment: These warnings you can ignore. They are just that. There is a github issue related to this and a pull request. It just needs to be incorporated in the code base and republished to cran. I raised additional awareness for this issue with the package maintainer.

Comment: Oh okay, however the sma is not being added. I used (seemed to work for the 4 stocks from above): stock_data <- stock_data %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = ema.t)

Comment: Should work fine. The only thing I see is that you only get 1 value when you use `ema.t = 200` due to the low amount of records. but try with `stock_data <- stock_data %>% group_by(symbol) %>% tq_mutate(select = adjusted, mutate_fun = SMA, n = ema.t, col_rename = "sma200")`. The col_rename option to make sure you are not overwritting an existing column.

Comment: I still get an error yet I think it's related to stocks having less then 200 entries. Tried to solve this (since I want to ommit those stocks) using: for(ticker in tickers){
  if(nrow(stock_data$symbol == ticker) < ema.t){
    stock_data[-c(stock_data$symbol == ticker)]
  }
}     but it gives: Error in if (nrow(stock_data$symbol == ticker) < ema.t) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In stock_data$symbol == ticker :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: switched nrow for sum but still gives the same error

Comment: `stock_data %>% group_by(symbol) %>% filter(nrow(.) >= ema.t)` will filter out all tickers with rows less than 200. after that, just work as normal.